# JTextPane highlight text

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

Can I highlight some text into a `JTextPane` starting from a value and ending from another value
like the following but with the yellow color?

""
JTextPane **highlight** text ""

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As often there are several possibilities, depending on what you really mean by "highlight":-)

Highlight by changing any style attributes of arbitrary text parts on the document level, something like

```
    SimpleAttributeSet sas = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    StyleConstants.setForeground(sas, Color.YELLOW);
    doc.setCharacterAttributes(start, length, sas, false);
```

Highlight via a Highlighter on the textPane level:

```
    DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter highlightPainter = 
        new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.YELLOW);
    textPane.getHighlighter().addHighlight(startPos, endPos, 
            highlightPainter);
```

Comment: Is the #2 a correct use of the Highlighter? The [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textapi.html#carrots) defines it to be for "highlight the current selection" (cit.) which I think refers to getSelectedText().

Comment: @ignis +1 for reading the tutorial :-) But I think it's poorly worded: it's whole purpose is to add custom highlighting. Read on in the api doc of Highlighter _allows to mark up the background with colored areas_ and its addHighlight _the beginning/end of the range_

Answer (score 10):

https://web.archive.org/web/20120530071821/http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.text/style_HiliteWords.html

```
JTextArea textComp = new JTextArea();

// Highlight the occurrences of the word "public"
highlight(textComp, "public");

// Creates highlights around all occurrences of pattern in textComp
public void highlight(JTextComponent textComp, String pattern)
{
    // First remove all old highlights
    removeHighlights(textComp);

    try
    {
        Highlighter hilite = textComp.getHighlighter();
        Document doc = textComp.getDocument();
        String text = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());
        int pos = 0;

        // Search for pattern
        // see I have updated now its not case sensitive 
        while ((pos = text.toUpperCase().indexOf(pattern.toUpperCase(), pos)) >= 0)
        {
            // Create highlighter using private painter and apply around pattern
            hilite.addHighlight(pos, pos+pattern.length(), myHighlightPainter);
            pos += pattern.length();
        }
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
    }
}

// Removes only our private highlights
public void removeHighlights(JTextComponent textComp)
{
    Highlighter hilite = textComp.getHighlighter();
    Highlighter.Highlight[] hilites = hilite.getHighlights();
    for (int i=0; i<hilites.length; i++)
    {
        if (hilites[i].getPainter() instanceof MyHighlightPainter)
        {
            hilite.removeHighlight(hilites[i]);
        }
    }
}

// An instance of the private subclass of the default highlight painter
Highlighter.HighlightPainter myHighlightPainter = new MyHighlightPainter(Color.red);

// A private subclass of the default highlight painter
class MyHighlightPainter extends DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter
{
    public MyHighlightPainter(Color color)
    {
        super(color);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Makky-It works fine and thanks for the post But when searching "makky" it highlights only "makky" but not "Makky", "MAKKY". Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: @Makky-Thanks a lot. :). This clears my first hurdle. Another hurdle is of highlighting 2 different words. I am giving a search feature where user can search a sentence. When the sentence is searched as phrase all is fine. But when as separate words I am unable to highlight all the words separately. Would you put some light on this ??

Comment: Hi . Glad that helped. Could you explain problem bit more ?

Comment: @Makky- say i searched "first hurdle" (as a phrase), then it is highlighting "first hurdle". These is bcoz these 2 words are consecutive, like a phrase. I want to search for both "first" and "hurdle" independently and highlight them too.

Comment: @Makky- I am using the code given above by you..;) nothing more than that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14454/discussion-between-john-and-makky)

Comment: ^ Sorry dude I don't know how to do that. There should be a way. By the way what the application you're trying to build may be I can help you @_

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can via the functions **setSelectionStart** and **setSelectionEnd** from **JTextComponent** which **JTextPane** inherits from.

see
[javadoc of JTextComponent.setSelectionStart](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setSelectionStart%28int%29)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try java's string comparison method

```
.equalsIgnoreCase("Search Target Text")
```

Because this method allows a search without having to take the case of a string into account
This might be the ticket to what you are trying to achieve

Hope this helps you Makky

Answer (score 0):

performance wise its better to put the toUpperCase on

String text = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());

rather than in the while loop

but thanks for the good example.