# How to highlight text in a document using Java?

Tags: java, text, highlighting

I would like to know if there is a free Java library or a piece of software written in java that can highlight (or change the font format of) a specific text in a document using Java?

I have found something called Aspose, but it hard to me to find some libraries in it, also it is not free.

Comment: Do you mean in a running Java GUI, or you need the 'highlight' to be included in the document when opened with other software?  What document types are of interest?

Comment: I need the highlight to be included in the document when opened. if i have a Microsoft word documents, i need to highlight a specific string (if found) in this document.

Comment: OK.. so that is 'word docs' is one format.  What *others?*  (And no - I don't want to play '20 questions' here - try and improve the quality of information your replies).

Comment: i think this link is good for you:
[JTextPane][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674128/jtextpane-highlight-text

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use HTML in your string. Make the highlight bold or give it a color. More information see link below.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html