# JTextPane highlighting based on regex?

Tags: swing, jtextpane

I would like to highlight words matching a regular expression in a JTextPane.

I've seen various examples but they all where very complicated with complete syntax highlighting. I just want to highlight (or set in bold) a word/sentence, is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If the overall underlying text of what is in the JTextPane is just a regular string and not HTML:

1. Get the underlying document from the JTextPane.

   `StyledDocument sdoc = textpane.getStyledDocument()`

**EDITED**: *changed to directly calling textPane.getStyledDocument, instead of casting the result of getDocument()*

2. Get the text of the document.

   `String text = sdoc.getText(0, sdoc.getLength())`
3. Use the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes to find the locations that match the regular expression.  I assume you already know how to do that.
4. For every location where a match is found, highlight the start to end of the matching substring with `sdoc.setCharacterAttributes` or use a highlighter (see [JTextPane highlight text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674128/jtextpane-highlight-text))