# Find/Replace dialog on jTextArea

Tags: java, netbeans

I have assigment to make notepad using NetBeans Java. I already made the whole thing, I just don't know how to implement find/replace dialog, can you help me with this. I'm using jTextArea.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: I only have textArea with Menu, nothing special. I have options like New, Open, Save etc. There is no need to show code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you already know about [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and how to make the appropriate dialog box (since you apparently have already made the `JTextArea` for the Notepad equivalent), and that you just want to know how to make it work on the back end.

What I would do is have a `Scanner` object go through your file to perform the find and replace.

```
String myAlteredText = "";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(myText);

while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    String next = scanner.next();
    if(next.equals(userFindInput)) {
        myAlteredText += userReplaceInput;
    }
    else {
        myAlteredText += next;
    }
    myAlteredText += " ";
}
```

You can use `.equalsIgnoreCase()` if case doesn't matter.  Likewise, you can tweak to adjust to your user parameters (i.e., if it doesn't have to match the whole word, use `.contains()` instead).  There may be some nit-picky other things you need to do to maintain abnormal spacing and line breaks, but this is the general approach I would use.

Comment: what's "myText", is that text from textArea? and how to highlight the word(s) I found in textArea.

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming `myText` is the text in your Notepad-equivalent.  For highlighting techniques, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674128/jtextpane-highlight-text).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JTable although this is rather unconventional. You could load each word into a new cell. This way when you need to replace 1 word you don't need to update the entire jtextarea for just 1 character unless I am mistaken. This would require a lot of work however in order to get this to work