# JscrollPane/JTree/JTextpane on scroll showing <Error>: CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix in red color in swing

Tags: macos, swing, scroll, tree, jtextpane

When i scroll the content of JTree/JTextPane, i can see RED lines coming in console in Mac 10.11 or later.

```
"Jun  1 13:31:19  java[1031] <Error>: CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix.
```

Jun  1 13:31:19  java[1031] : CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix.
Jun  1 13:31:19  java[1031] : CGAffineTransformInvert: singular"

It looks like error since it is in red color. but my program is working fine. so i just wanted to knows what is this singular matrix in mac and why  is it showing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting font size to 0 causes CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019481/setting-font-size-to-0-causes-cgaffinetransforminvert-singular-matrix-error)

Comment: Oracle maintains the code, now; Apple just reports the errors; for reference, please edit your question with a [mcve] that mentions version numbers.